# building nuget packages in teamcity

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, nuget

I have this almost working.

I push a sln  to github and then the build is triggered in Team city.

Binaries are built and placed in bin\release folders for each project.

I then have separate Nuget Pack build steps to create the packages.

My problem is probably very simple but i cant see how to place the dlls in a lib folder. The lib folder (and net version) is not auto created when the pack takes place which is a shame.

Currently the pack step builds the packs fine but doesnt place the dlls in a lib folder. So they are not referenced when the package is installed.

Is there some command arg i can do to dynamically create the lib folder and place the dlls inside. Whats the best practice here? Should this be setup in VS. If so how can i prevent TC overriding this and placing the dll in newly created bin/release folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can state which files you want to pack by creating a nuspec file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>me</authors>
    <description>Description</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyPackage.dll" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then run `pack` command on the nuspec file.

```
NuGet.exe pack MyPackage.nuspec
```